# MySQL: default value of column from another table column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, default

Consider you have table `USER` which has primary key on field `USER_ID`. And every table in your db should contain `MODIFIED_BY` field with id of actual user. My aim is to specify default value on that field which equals id of user with appropriate name. F.E. you have user with name `system` and you want every record of every table to have id of this user in `MODIFIED_BY` field. As well you want all the new records to satisfy this.

Comment: You want `USER()`.

Comment: didn't understand what do you mean

Comment: Does every user have their own login to the database?  Or are you using a single Id for a connection string and have a "user" table which contains application user credentials? or something else?

Comment: I'm a little confused. Do you have a question?

Comment: @antongarakh . . . In many situations, you can use the database security mechanisms to identify users.  The `USER()` function provides information about the current connected user.  If you are managing security and logins yourself, then this might not be the right solution.

Comment: I think it extremely unlikely that USER() would be of any use to you in this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are referring to other sorts of users than database users (e.g. 'registered users'), maybe triggers are the solution to your problem. With two triggers, one fired when inserting and one when updating, you can specify the value of a `modified_at`-column using custom code, e.g. `select user_id from ... where ...`

Please check the following sample code, which should directly answer your question; hope it solves your problem. Otherwise, please give us more information / some more context.

```sql
DELIMITER |

drop table if exists sometable
|
CREATE TABLE `sometable` (
  `somecolumn` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
)
|
drop table if exists registered_user
|
CREATE TABLE registered_user (
  user_id integer primary key,
  name varchar(50)
)
|
drop trigger if exists sometable_inserted
|
drop trigger if exists sometable_modified
|
CREATE TRIGGER sometable_inserted BEFORE INSERT ON sometable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET new.modified_by := (select user_id from registered_user where name=@name);
END;
|
CREATE TRIGGER sometable_modified BEFORE UPDATE ON sometable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET new.modified_by := (select user_id from registered_user where name=@name);
END;
|

DELIMITER ;

insert into registered_user values (5, 'joe');
insert into registered_user values (6, 'sam');

set @name='sam';
insert into sometable(somecolumn) values (1);
insert into sometable(somecolumn) values (2);
set @name='joe';
update sometable set somecolumn = 3 where somecolumn = 2;
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I need! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. If it solved your problem, please be so kind to mark the answer as 'accepted'.