# MySQL select default value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have foreign key in one table, references on another table, not null. How can I select the default value for it? 
Something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE table_a MODIFY COLUMN not_null_column BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT
    (SELECT id FROM table_b WHERE name_field = 'some name');
```

Or this:

```
SET @defaultValue = (SELECT id FROM table_b WHERE name_field = 'some name');
ALTER TABLE table_a MODIFY COLUMN not_null_column BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT @defaultValue;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql set field default value to other column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15384429/mysql-set-field-default-value-to-other-column)

Comment: hmm, I think I really meant this one: [MySQL: default value of column from another table column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41102020/mysql-default-value-of-column-from-another-table-column) But it seems the 1st one indicates the real answer just as well: It can't be done.

Comment: Yes, it this. Thank you. Didn't think that there is impossible to define a function or expression as a default value, so, skipped this question while searching.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: default value of column from another table column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41102020/mysql-default-value-of-column-from-another-table-column)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use [13.5 Prepared SQL Statement Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

```sql
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table_b`, `table_a`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table_a` (
    ->   `not_null_column` VARCHAR(20)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table_b` (
    ->   `name_field` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    ->   `value` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `table_b`
    ->   (`name_field`, `value`)
    -> VALUES
    ->  ('some name', '5');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DESC `table_a`;
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| not_null_column | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @`stmt` := CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `table_a`
    '>                        MODIFY COLUMN `not_null_column` BIGINT NOT NULL
    '>                        DEFAULT ', (SELECT `value`
    ->                                    FROM `table_b`
    ->                                    WHERE `name_field` = 'some name'));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT @`stmt`;
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| @`stmt`                                                                                                                       |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ALTER TABLE `table_a`
                       MODIFY COLUMN `not_null_column` BIGINT NOT NULL
                       DEFAULT 5 |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> PREPARE `stmt` FROM @`stmt`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Statement prepared

mysql> EXECUTE `stmt`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> DEALLOCATE PREPARE `stmt`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DESC `table_a`;
+-----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| not_null_column | bigint(20) | NO   |     | 5       |       |
+-----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Example [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ojnfFZwhxroDbDNsjYg1Jx/0).